# How to use the signal pre_save?

Tags: python, django

How can use the signal pre_save in django for remove the old image and save the new image.
The code in models.py is:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender = Treballador)
def treballador_removing(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    this = Video.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
    if this.photo == self.photo:
        instance.photo.delete(False)`
```

What do bad?

Comment: What makes you think `self` is the object you intend to access?

Comment: I think you meant `instance.pk`. `self` is undefined. Why go back to the database? You already have the `instance`